# how to click on usercontrol to open anoter usercontrol?

Tags: winforms, user-controls, c#-4.0

im using visual c# 2008,i have tried to open  usercontrol2 from  usercontrol1. using event handling yet still unable to load the usercontrol1, but able to close the usercontrol1.

please help me..

Comment: post your tried code, it may help to solve the problem

Comment: You're supposed to be opening new *forms*, not usercontrols. You stick them *on* a form like a button or any other control. It sounds like your design is seriously broken.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a Try

```
void UserControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl2 u2 = new UserControl2();
        this.Parent.Controls.Add(u2); // if you want to add to parent
        //this.Controls.Add(u2); // if you want to add to the first UserControl
        u2.BringToFront();
        this.Visible = false;
        u2.Visible = true;
    }
```

I think your problem is that you did not assign usercontrol2 
to a parents control collection.